# When Class method same name php function

Tags: php

Consider this code:

```
class some_class extends someother_class
{

function delete()
{
    delete($somefile); // <-- That refers to the PHP function called delete

    parent::delete();  // <-- That refers to the delete() method in the parent class
}

}
```

How do I use the PHP function delete from within the delete method in the extended class?

Comment: use some_class::delete($somefile); instead...

Comment: The above doesn't work.  I can call the parent::delete() no problem, but it dies when it tries to delete($somefile).

Comment: Well, `delete()` is not a standard function of PHP; not sure what you expected to happen ;-)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.delete.php

Comment: Doh, you are right Jack.  I didn't read the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `call_user_func_array()` here:

```
class some_class extends someother_class
{

    function delete()
    {
        call_user_func_array('delete', array($somefile)); 

        parent::delete();  
    }

}
```